# Testing file copy, move, delete operations in Ruby

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, tdd

I am developing a backup library in Ruby. And, as you may expect, there are many files copied, moved and deleted during the backup. In my test I want to make sure that the proper files and folders are copied from source to destination. What are the best practices of testing it? Should I deal with physical files during the tests? Or is it better to mock it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit tests need to run fast, so that they can be run very often, after each change. So touching the file system is not an option here.

Then integration tests (or whatever they can be called) will ensure the physical files are actually copied. These tests can be slower, as they are run less often.

Answer (score 3):

It is better to avoid using real filesystem for testing (it results in slow, brittle tests with messy setup/cleanup). Better to stub it out, with `fakefs` gem, for example.